# Incomplete output with psycopg2 and csv writer in python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.6, psycopg2, rhel

I wrote the following python code that would write a portion of a postgresql table to a csv file using psycopg2 and python's csvwriter.  The problem that I am having is that I get an incomplete csv file and I am not sure why.  Typically, what I see is about 80 to 90% of the table in the csv file and usually the last row outputted in the csv file is incomplete as well.  Running Python2.6.6 on RHEL6.4.  Looking for some help for a work around on this issue.

```
import psycopg2
import csv

connection = psycopg2.connect('dbname=db user=user password=pass host=localhost port=5555')
cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute('SELECT title,date,publisher,author FROM books;')
with open('books.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    csvwriter.writerow(['title,date,publisher,author'])
    for record in cursor:
        csvwriter.writerow(record)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: I created a 20k rows table trying to reproduce without success. What are the OS and python versions?

Comment: Python2.6.6 on RHEL6.4.

Comment: That really sounds like something crashed.  Check logs everywhere, maybe run it through a debugger to see what your problem is.  If the last line is incomplete, then the crash sounds like it occurs inside csvwriter.